# Java: variable from parent class in child one isn't initialized and holds null

Tags: java, variables, initialization, parent

```
Parent class(*ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender*):

     ...

   protected String fileName = null;

   public FileAppender() {
      }

          public void setFile(String file) {
            if (file == null) {
              fileName = file;
            } else {
              // Trim spaces from both ends. The users probably does not want
              // trailing spaces in file names.
              String val = file.trim();
              fileName = val;
            }
          }
    ...
```

Child class:

```
    ...
   public class FileAppender<E> extends ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender<E> {

     private FileResourceManager frm  = new FileResourceManager(fileName, tempDir, false, loggerFacade);


     public void writeOut(E event) throws IOException {
      Object txId = null;
      try {
       frm.start();
       txId = frm.generatedUniqueTxId();
       frm.startTransaction(txId);
       outputStream = frm.writeResource(txId, fileName, true);
       outputStream.write(event.toString().getBytes());
       frm.commitTransaction(txId);

      }

      catch (Exception e) {
    ...
      }
     }
```

The problem is that `fileName` is passed as null to `frm` in this line:

```
private FileResourceManager frm  = new FileResourceManager(fileName, tempDir, false, loggerFacade);
```

How can i create `frm` instance,with not-null `fileName`,e.g. already initialized in parent?

Comment: `setFile` isn't related to the question, it's not called from anywhere. You'd better show constructor taking string instead (the one you invoke in `new SomeClass(fileName)`).

Comment: Please provide a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. It's really not clear what classes you have at the moment.

Comment: @Jon: i've edited post and inserted concrete code,and the idea remained the same

Comment: This is far from a short but complete program. We want to help you - please make it easy for us to do so. Read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved with following code:

```
private static FileResourceManager frm;
    public void writeOut(E event) throws IOException {
        ...

        if (frm == null) {
            frm = new FileResourceManager(fileName, tempDir, false, loggerFacade);
        }

        Object txId = null;
        try {
...
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
...
}
    }
```

`fileName` is initialized(not null) within writeOut() method.
Not very gracefully,but looks like simplest solution in my case.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you can do one of the following:

- call setFile(file) in constructor of child class
- implement logics placed in setFile() method in child's constructor (BTW, that'll be code duplication)
- if parent class provides constructor, which accepts file parameter, call parent's constructor with super(file) in constructor of child class

**UPDATE**

AFAIU, the problem is in fields initialization order. The moving "frm" field initialization into child class constructor should solve the problem:

```
public FileAppender(String fileName) {
    setFile(fileName);
    frm  = new FileResourceManager(fileName, tempDir, false, loggerFacade);
    ...
}
```

Comment: logic of setFile() in child class should be the same - I needn't code duplication, I just need that my child class has already initialized fileName param. See my post edited, i inserted real code snippets.

Comment: parent class has only no-param constructur(ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender)

Comment: Updated answer in accordance with comments.

Comment: Kel, i can't cretae parametrized constructor in child:Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext] ... caused by:java.lang.InstantiationException: xxx.common.logging.FileAppender

Comment: Then how would you like to pass fileName to instance of child class?

Comment: Good question, anyway the direction you described is correct.I'm investigating this issue. afaui, is it eligible create child constructor with params ,when parent contains no-param constructor only?

Comment: I don't see any problems with that.

Answer (score 2):

Is `setFile` an override that you are calling from the parent class constructor? In that case: The parent class constructor runs before the useful part fo the child constructor. So `setFile` is called from the parent class constructor, and then control is returned to the child class constructor which you have nulling out that variable.

The instance field initialisers and instance initialisers are actually part of constructors, after the possibly implicit call to super (but not if they call `this()`). I believe C sharp inserts instance initialisers before the call to super (but they can't reference `this`).

What to do: Avoiding inheritance is always good. In particular avoid protected variables and calling overridable methods from constructors. Keep constructors simple. And don't add `= null` to instance fields.

Comment: setFile() is method in parent class,that initialize fileName param. see my post updated.I need to get already setted fileName in child class when do new for child class instance field.

Comment: So where is `setFile` being called from. In the new code, you are using the field from the derived class constructor (via an instance field initialiser). So unless you are calling it from the base class constructor, it doesn't look like you'll have set the field before use.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the setFile() method in the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your "parent class" is the SomeClass class, overwrite the default constructor there:

```
public Someclass(String fileName) {
   this.fileName = fileName;
}
```